# Google Maps Autocomplete - only cities and postal code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

is it possible to restrict the autocomplete search only to cities and postal code?

This won't work:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                    {types: ['(cities', '(postal_code)'], componentRestrictions: {country: "de"}});
```

Maybe this is right?

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                    {types: ['(regions)'], componentRestrictions: {country: "de"}});
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

But autocomplete also show some results outside my restricted country, why?

[image]

Some suggestions?

**Solution**

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                    {types: ['(regions)'], componentRestrictions: {'country': "de"}});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below is the correct answer to my question.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                    {types: ['(regions)'], componentRestrictions: {'country': "de"}});
```

Comment: This includes federal states as well, is there a solution with is Cities and ZIP only?

Comment: I think no solution out of the box.